# ASP.NET jQuery Datepicker Issue - What am I missing?

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui

This was working on Friday, and now isn't.  I've got this at the beginning of a UserControl:

```
<link type="text/css" href="/App_Themes/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#MainContent_ucSearchControl_dpPickupStart").datepicker();
        $("#MainContent_ucSearchControl_dpPickupEnd").datepicker();
});
</script>
```

And further down, this:

```
 <td><asp:TextBox id="dpPickupStart" runat="server"  style="width: 65px"/></td>
 <td><asp:TextBox id="dpPickupEnd" runat="server" style="width: 65px"/></td>
```

Which results in (in the rendered page) input controls with:

```
name="ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$ucSearchControl$dpPickupStart" id="MainContent_ucSearchControl_dpPickupStart"
name="ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$ucSearchControl$dpPickupEnd" id="MainContent_ucSearchControl_dpPickupEnd"
```

And yet, every time the page loads, I get an Object Expected javascript error which points to the $(document).ready location.

What am I missing?

EDIT:  Firebug is reporting that:
$ is not defined
[Break On This Error] $(document).ready(function () {

Comment: In similar situations, I've found it a _lot_ easier to target elements based on classes, rather than id's (that Asp.net munges during generation)

Comment: Browse to the URL ins Firefox+Firebug and see if the jquery related files are indeed having valid reponse code returned by the Server?

Comment: A couple things.  First, avoid hard-coding the control ID.  Instead, use <%= dpPickupStart.ClientID %> for the ID, since it can change. Also, it may be for brevity, but you should be linking to the CSS in the head of the page, not in the top of your User Control.  You may have a Head content section, which makes my point moot.

Comment: getting the id of ASP.Net controls like that is not very good.. please see this blog post: http://clientguy.blogspot.com/2011/03/jquery-selector-for-net-controls.html  for other solutions.

Comment: All of the suggestions are good in terms of what shd be used for the element selection, however here the problem is merely not with the id, instead bad src url for one of the jquery files since the error is Object Expected and $(<something>) will always return an object.

Comment: Use Chrome Dev tools or Firebug and see which resources aren't loading. You can also use the console to type stuff in and see what the browser is seeing.

Comment: @guy schaller - I can't disagree more strongly with you. `<%= dpPickupStart.ClientID %>` is the perfect way to get a .NET control's ID.  The method outlined in your blog not only adds the overhead of an additional function call, it circumvents jQuery's ID selector optimization. Now instead of doing a simple `document.getElementById`, jQuery has to do lots of complex DOM traversal to find your element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being a user control you cannot guarantee that the relative path to your JS files will always be correct depending on the location of the parent page in the file system hierarchy.

Therefore change you JS script tags as follows to use the [Control.ResolveUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveurl.aspx) method which converts a URL into one that is usable on the requesting client.

```
<script src='<%=ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")%>' type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src='<%=ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.min.js")%>' type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Or reference from a CDN for added performace bonus of caching.

[jQuery hosted on google](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js)
[jQuery UI hosted on google](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/jquery-ui.min.js)

Comment: I now have both src="<%=ResolveUrl("/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")%>" and $("#<%= dpPickupStart.ClientID %>").datepicker(), which produces the same html, and the same error.

Comment: @michael sorry, wrong quotes, try the code again. You could try an external reference to prove the point. If it still fails with an external reference it narrows the problem down.

Comment: I actually had to change this to use the ~ notation before it started finding it again.  How this changed from Saturday, I have no idea...

Comment: @Michael Thanks for the update, I have updated the code example for future reference

Comment: was stuck on this for a while.  Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

That error is caused due to Jquery not available. I think Swaff's solution should work(+1). Check if you have the Jquery-1.5.1.min.js file is available in Scripts folder of your solution. Or it could also be that your Scripts folder is renamed.

HTH.